# MobileFFMPeg Not converting mkv to Mp4

Tags: swift, ffmpeg

I'm currently running the following code on my device in order to convert all mkv files in a directory to an mp4. But for some reason no files are converted. I double checked the dir name and it is correct, is there something wrong with my syntax?

```
let path = self.documentsDir()
let url = URL(string: path.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)
     var rc = MobileFFmpeg.execute("-i jellyfish.mkv -c:v libx264 -preset -slow -crf 22 -c:a copy youroutput.mp4")
          if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
               print("Command execution completed successfully.\n");
                } 
          else if (rc == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
                print("Command execution cancelled by user.\n");
                } 
           else {
                print("Command execution failed with rc=%d and output=%@.\n", rc, MobileFFmpegConfig.getLastCommandOutput);
                }
```

```
2020-05-07 13:36:02.782150-0400 WebmBrowser[8025:138754] ERROR: /Users/jlee/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8CD81B87-9E27-4F3C-8601-C76945FAD4D8/data/Containers/Data/Application/B7A0D956-3BAB-4203-82EE-5FDBF38B2F13/Documents/jellyfish.mkv: Invalid data found when processing input

Command execution failed with rc=%d and output=%@.
```

Comment: No errors? Does it fail before executing `ffmpeg`? Is the problem with the code or with `ffmpeg`? Can you show the log from `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Made changes to original post

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fully address my questions. Run the same `ffmpeg` command in Terminal using the same inputs. Does the command work? If yes, then it suggests that the problem is with the swift code and not with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Using ffmpeg in the console works fine so I think the problem might be with the MobileFFMPEG framework.

Comment: Another thing to try is adding the `-report` option to the ffmpeg command. Then look for the log file in the working directory. It will be named something like `ffmpeg-20200507-105001.log`. If it does not exist then you can assume that `ffmpeg` did not even execute.